# Sorting a list of integers using Z3 python

Tags: python, sorting, integer, z3, z3py

I'm looking for the fastest way to sort a list of integers using Z3. So far, I currently implemented two different algorithms: the first one can only handle lists that do not contain any duplicate value. The second one is an implementation of the bubble sort algorithm, which can sort any kind of integer list, but appears to be quite slow if the list length increases (the algo is O(n**2), don't know for the first one). Below is the code to test both and benchmark their performances.

Has anyone implemented a better sorting algorithm (Merge/Heap/QuickSort)? What would be your advice to increase performance (reduce the number of assertions and/or decrease computation time)?

```py
from z3 import *
from time import perf_counter

def sort_list_of_z3_var(lst):
    """Sort a list of integers that have different values"""
    n = len(lst)
    # create the z3 IntSort list
    a = [FreshInt() for i in range(n)]
    asst = []
    # add the related assertions
    for i in range(n):
        asst.append(Or([a[i] == lst[j] for j in range(n)]))
    asst.append(And([a[i] < a[i + 1] for i in range(n - 1)]))
    return a, asst

def sort_bubble(lst):
    """Take a list of int variables, return the list of new variables
    sorted using the bubble recursive sort"""
    cstr = [] # list of assertions to be returned
    n = len(lst)
    # create the z3 IntSort list
    sorted_list = [FreshInt() for i in range(n)]
    # fill in the variable list
    i = 0
    for s in sorted_list:
        cstr.append(s == lst[i])
        i += 1

    def bubble_up(arr):
        new_asst = []
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            x = arr[i]
            y = arr[i + 1]
            # compare and swap x and y
            x1, y1 = FreshInt(), FreshInt()
            c = If(x <= y, And(x1 == x, y1 == y), And(x1 == y, y1 == x))
            # store values
            arr[i] = x1
            arr[i + 1] = y1
            new_asst.append(c)
        return arr, new_asst

    # recursive call to bubble_up
    for _ in range(len(sorted_list)):
        sorted_list, cst = bubble_up(sorted_list)
        cstr.extend(cst)
    return sorted_list, cstr

# define 2 lists to be sorted
integer_list_distinct = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
integer_list_not_distinct = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

# first algorithm
z3_vars_1, z3_assertions_1 = sort_list_of_z3_var(integer_list_distinct)
s = Solver()
s.add(z3_assertions_1)
time_1 = perf_counter()
s.check()
time_2 = perf_counter()
solution_1 = s.model()
result_1 = [solution_1[v].as_long() for v in z3_vars_1]
print(result_1)
print("Time Alg.1:", time_2 - time_1)

# second algorithm
z3_vars_2, z3_assertions_2 = sort_bubble(integer_list_distinct)
s2 = Solver()
s2.add(z3_assertions_2)
time_3 = perf_counter()
s2.check()
time_4 = perf_counter()
solution_2 = s2.model()
result_2 = [solution_2[v].as_long() for v in z3_vars_2]
print(result_2)
print("Time Alg.2:", time_4 - time_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

With symbolic inputs, I don't think you can do any better than `O(n^2)`. Bottom line, all of these will end-up doing pair-wise comparisons. Some might perform better if your list has constant values in them; but that's not really the interesting case, after all. And performance measurements of this sort is rather problematic as you don't really know how these constraints will interact with all the others in your system; and different algorithms might perform differently based on other constraints present.

Having said that, I think this is an interesting problem to think about. My hunch was doing a variant of radix sort might be a good idea, especially in the presence of duplicate elements. The idea is you turn the list into a an array of integers, counting the presence of each element. I call this "bagifying" though the name isn't perfect. Then, you assert that the "bagified" version of your original and the sorted version is the same. Here's how you'd code that in z3py:

```py
def bagSort(s, lst):
    n = len(lst)

    bag = K(IntSort(), 0)
    for i in lst:
       bag = Store(bag, i, bag[i] + 1)

    result = [FreshInt() for i in range(n)]
    resultBag = K(IntSort(), 0)
    for i in result:
        resultBag = Store(resultBag, i, resultBag[i] + 1)

    for i in range(n-1):
        s.add(result[i] <= result[i+1])

    for i in lst:
        s.add(bag[i] == resultBag[i])   

    s.check()
    m = s.model()
    return [m[i] for i in result]
```

And use it like this:

```py
s = Solver()
print(bagSort(s, integer_list_not_distinct))
```

In a few simple tests this all constants, I found that your bubble-sort performs better than `bagSort`: So I guess creating and manipulating arrays has extra costs that cannot be avoided. But this could be another trick and might perform better (perhaps?) if the input has a lot of symbolic values with lots of other constraints. Of course, this is speculation.

Measuring performance is hard for algorithms running on concrete values, and it can really be tricky in the presence of symbolic expressions. Unless this is mere curiosity, I'd recommend trying all these approaches on your actual problem and pick the one that performs better; keeping in mind different instances of the problem might benefit from different algorithms.